# Django, how to set group based permissions

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project which has different types of users. Each group of user should be able to access some pages and be restricted to access other pages.
I saw various solutions for this like.
Some assign users to specific groups and then write a custom decorators to restrict pages like

```
def allowed_users(groups=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            group = None

            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            if group in groups:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("You are not authorize to view this page ")
        
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator


@allowed_users(groups=["admin"])
def products(request):
    pass
```

and some tutorials and books recommend to assign user to groups and then give permissions to each group. like

```
admin_group.set.permissions([list_of_permissions])
admin_group.add.permissions(per1, per2, ...)
```

a quote which says

> Note: do not check the user in the group to verify whether the users have permission or not, so must use has_perm because at the bottom line user will inherit the permissions from the assigned groups and you can use groups to categorize users if your intention was just to use a User Role model alternative.

My question is, which method is appropriate and why? and if we prefer the first method doesn't it break the role of normalization in databases concepts because we actually don't have a permission table. It's just like applying permission virtually, and unreal.

Thanks